# HangMan removing letters guessed from array

Tags: java, arrays

I have hit a road block while programming my hangman program I help with removing the letters I have already correctly Guessed from my array here is my Code :

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
    public Game(){

        start();

    }

    public static void start()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        String [] Words = {"Dog","cat","Food","Bacon","Turkey","hood","poo","Good","look"};//initializes the array
        String RandomWord = Words[rand.nextInt(Words.length)];//picks a random word from the char array and stores it in a variabe
        char [] array = RandomWord.toCharArray();//converts the randomly generated word from the array into a char array
        int i = 0;//counter
        char input = 0;
        int WinCounter = 0;//counts the number of wins
        System.out.println("You have a "+RandomWord.length()+" letter word "+RandomWord);
        int tries = 20;
        int wrongCounter = 0;
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

        while(i<tries){

            i++;

            hangMan(wrongCounter);


            System.out.println("Guess a letter : ");
            input = scan.next().charAt(0);
            list.add(input);
            System.out.println("Guessed Letters are : "+guessedLetters(input,list));

            for(int j = 0; j<noDuplicates(array).length;j++){

                if(findCorrect(array,input, list)+removeCaseSensitive(array,input)>0){
                    j++;

                    System.out.println("You got it right");
                    //System.out.println(noRepeat(list,input));
                    WinCounter++;
                    break;

                }
                else if(!(input ==noDuplicates(array)[j])){

                    System.out.println("You got it wrong");
                    //System.out.println(noRepeat(list,input));
                    wrongCounter++;
                    break;


                }

            }
            if(WinCounter == noDuplicates(array).length)//tests to see if the player won
            {
                System.out.println("You have Won!");
                break;
            }
            else if(hangMan(wrongCounter)){
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean hangMan(int wrongCounter) {
        boolean isOver= false;
        System.out.println("------------|");
        switch(wrongCounter){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("|           O");
            break;
        case 2 :
            System.out.println("|           O");
            System.out.print("|          /");

            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("|           O");
            System.out.print("|          /|\\");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        case 4 : 
            System.out.println("|           O");
            System.out.print("|          /|\\");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("|          /");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("|           O");
            System.out.print("|          /|\\");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("|          / \\");
            System.out.println("You lost");
            isOver = true;
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<7;i++)
            System.out.println("|");
        return isOver;

    }

    //removes all duplicates from the array
    private static char[] noDuplicates(char[] a) {
        HashSet<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>();
        char[] result = new char[a.length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (keys.add((int) a[i])) {
                result[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(result, j);
    }
    //tests to see if the users input it equal to any of the letters in the array
    public static int findCorrect(char [] a,char Input,ArrayList list){

        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<noDuplicates(a).length;i++){
            if(noDuplicates(a)[i]==Input)
                count++;


        }
        return count;
    }
    //removes case sensitivity 
    public static int removeCaseSensitive(char [] a,char Input){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<noDuplicates(a).length;i++)
        {

            if(Character.toLowerCase(Input)==Character.toLowerCase(noDuplicates(a)[i]))
                count++;
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(Input)==Character.toUpperCase(noDuplicates(a)[i]))
                count++;


        }
        return count;

    }
    public static String guessedLetters(char input,ArrayList List){
        List.add(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(List.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(List.get(i));
            if (i < List.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();   


    }

}
```

Any suggestions you guys have would be great I am out of ideas

Comment: I would suggest you tell us what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a List rather than an Array and then you can use the list remove() method to remove items.

Comment: A `Set` would probably be better -- more efficient (though with the small size of most alphabets, that's not a big deal) and more semantically appropriate. The OP is probably trying to keep track of the _set_ of guessed (or remaining unguessed) letters.

Comment: For the size of an alphabet it is unlikely to actually be more efficient - the extra complexity, memory usage, etc of a set isn't worthwhile for small collections unless you really need to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: But I agree, `Set` should be considered for this case.

Comment: the thing is I have based my whole program on arrays or at least most of it so I would have to go change the whole thing

Comment: Welcome to programming. Refactoring is a good thing, not a bad one and as you learn you will find yourself doing it all the time (I still do!) :) Arrays are very limited, use a collection, honestly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I just started programming at the beginning of the school year ,and I was doing this to build some logic skills and to learn new things about programming and java.